# RDBMS: How to model a company having different products at multiple locations

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

I have an existing database that models all `products`, a `company` is either producing or consuming. The database is quite simple:

```
Table: companies {PK: company_id}
+------------+--------------+
| company_id | company_name |
+------------+--------------+

Table: products {PK: product_id}
+------------+--------------+---------------+
| company_id | product_id   | product_price |
+------------+--------------+---------------+
```

Now, if I need to add `location` information to it, it starts to get complicated. 
Basically, now a `company` has many `locations` and each `location` has many `products`.

To further complicate matters, some attributes of the `product` e.g. `price` may not be the same at each `location`. I would like to share other common attributes at all `locations` (Basically, I want to avoid creating three copies of product A that's used at all three locations).

I'm not sure what the best way to model this is. I can think of

```
Table: company_location
+------------+-------------+
| company_id | location_id |
+------------+-------------+

Table: location_product
+-------------+------------+
| location_id | product_id |
+-------------+------------+
```

But this design would not allow `product` attributes to change per `location`, without creating an entirely different product for each location. I also don't have a way to maintain a master `product` list per `company`.

Any help is appreciated.

PS: I'm using a postgreSQL database

Comment: Note: this is almost the monkey-wrench example in the Chris Date book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules of normalization would tell you that you need your non-key attributes to depend on **all of the key values** (and nothing else).

If price is determined by:
 - The company who makes it
 - The location that sells it
 - What the product actually is

Then that implies that `PRICE` needs a candidate key that specifies company, location and production.

The issue becomes what the relationships are between companies, products and locations.  Also, what else do you know (what columns do you have) about these three kinds of things?

If they are all totally independent, for example, the products are commodities and don't depend at all on companies and the locations are independent distributors, which have nothing to do with either companies or what kind of products are sold there, then really a single three-way join is probably your best bet.

However, if there are *some* linkages between company, product and location, then you need to normalize these items out appropriately.  At the end, you may still find yourself tempted to keep price as the only attribute in a three-way join.  Alternatively, you may find that your data is actually more hierarchical (companies have locations which sell products that are fundamentally different in some meaningful way from similar products sold at other locations).  In such a case the price *might* live on the leaf level of a tree structure.

It's really hard to say for sure what would work best for you without understanding your business rules better.

The bottom line is, **you should aim for third normal form (3NF).**

You probably want something like this:
[image: ERD]

Comment: A `company` has several `locations`, like factories. They're all owned by the `company` and they're not independent entities. `products` could be what the company manufactures and also what it uses (bill of materials) to manufacture those `products`. Not all `locations` manufacture or consume all `products` in the `companies` master list. Also, a `product` price (selling or buying) may be different in different locations but other attributes remain same. Other attributes of the product are - name, description, purchase price, selling price, taxes, etc.

Comment: @CodePoet - It sounds to me like company and location are related in a one to many - In other words, a location is not shared by multiple companies.  For products, however, it's still not clear if they belong to companies or if they are totally independent.  If they belong to companies, then you probably want one to many from companies to locations as well.  Then you have a `PRICE` table that intersects location and product (if product is M:1 with company).